# Fix loading 2 Favicon or Tab icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, favicon

http://www.1o5c.org/ pls help me fix this icon on the tab of browser. It loads 2 site icons. First one shows up then it is followed by the current icon.

i cant understand why it occurs. help me thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the 2 icons in your question so that we can see which is the new and which is the old?

Comment: sorry but i dont have the access. but the current one is the hand icon and the old one is a red square. sometimes the red square is not loading and is replaced by a paper icon then replaced by the hand icon.

Comment: I think that you need to do something with your website. It loads very slowly, because it makes 497 requests of total 10.6 MB! It took 50 seconds to load. Try using sprites for country flags.

Comment: i just don't understand why it is loading 2 icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both [`/favicon.ico`](http://www.1o5c.org/favicon.ico) file in a root folder of your project and `<link rel="shortcut icon"/>`, pointing to [another icon](http://www.1o5c.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/favicon.ico).

Remove `favicon.ico` file in your root folder, and it will stop loading two images.

Comment: Or, you can just replace the favicon.ico in your server root with the one you want to use.

Comment: sadly it's not the right icon it's a red square one :(